# Why doesn't iOS kill after short amount of time when I enter background?

Tags: ios, ios4

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{  
   NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
   for(int x=0;;)
      {
         NSLog(@"%d",x++);
         sleep(1);
      }
}
```

I press home button on simulator with latest iOS 4.x iOS. I figured it would be killed off after like 60 seconds, but its been going on for over 10 minutes printing x. There is nothing else going on in the app, its the skeleton "view" generated code created by Xcode.

Comment: Simulator or real ipod/iphone? The simulator does some weird things around minimizing, I forget if that was one of the specific oddities, but it might be.

Comment: Simulator. I thought I tried in on real HW last night and got same.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that you're "holding" the run loop by not letting applicationDidEnterBackground return. iOS needs to clean up after this returns so by not doing so, you're essentially waiting for the system to kill you, which it will do eventually at it's own discretion.

To prove this, remove your "for" loop and add the following to the top of your app delegate:

```
dispatch_source_t __timer1;
```

... and then add this to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
__timer1 = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
if (__timer1)
{
    dispatch_source_set_timer(__timer1, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(__timer1, ^{
        NSLog(@"ping1");
    });
    dispatch_resume(__timer1);
}
```

since now you're returning from applicationDidEnterBackground, you'll get the expected results, "ping1" will display every second until you enter the background.

Comment: Well, exactly, I want to hold it to prove to myself that iOS will kill me if I violate its rules. For instance, what if I just sat there in a tight loop and sucked CPU (hence battery). I would hope it would would kill me off since I'm not being nice to the system.

Comment: Indeed, you're testing an "edge case" and looks like you've found a bug. My device is still alive and kicking after holding the applicationDidEnterBackground method for 12 minutes, so I suggest you file a bug against apple (although you may want to verify against the 5.0 beda SDK first).

Comment: Ok, I've got iOS5 beta on a different system, so I'll try it out there this evening and see. Thanks.

Comment: Well, just downloaded latest Xcode4 beta and upgraded iPad1 to 5beta5 and ran same code on it and it acts the same way. Also let it run for over 12 minutes and it's not killed off.

Comment: Ok, just filed a bug report with Apple. Lets see if there is a response - maybe it's not a bug to them.

Comment: Got a response from Apple requesting Xcode project showing the issue. Uploaded it. I'll keep this thread updated with any feedback from Apple as to whether they think this is a problem.